# What to do with a Nikon D750 body that when switching lenses won't autofocus?

Tags: autofocus, nikon-d750

There was another similar question out there and one of the responders commented there was and he got his camera body replaced. I've been having the same issue with my new nikon just bought in January. Nikon wants me to send the body and lenses in to have it "looked at". I can't afford to go without the camera while they mess around with it.Does anyone have ideas as to how I can get this remedied better, quicker and without losing a camera?

Comment: This question lacks sufficient info.  Is this a "new" problem?  Did the lenses previously AF, then stop?  What lenses are being used?  Do all lenses not AF, or only some?  Do lenses not AF only after being switched? // Also, this question is over three years old.  How was it resolved?  Or have you been using it without AF all this time?

Answer (score 1):

> Nikon wants me to send the body and lenses in to have it "looked at". I can't afford to go without the camera while they mess around with it. Does anyone have ideas as to how I can get this remedied better, quicker and without losing a camera?

If "cannot afford to go without" is a matter of lost income as a working pro, you're in the US, and you own the qualifying gear (two bodies and two lenses on [this list](https://www.nikonpro.com/ProductList.aspx)), consider paying for a [Nikon Professional Services](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/service-and-support/nps/index.page) membership. At the Pro+ and Platinum+ levels, you qualify for loaners as well as discounted and priority repairs.  All the camera manufacturers have similar programs for professional users of their gear.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know how it is with Nikon, but with Canon (at least in Europe), there are certain certified repair shops that you can take your camera to and they will repair it. If it is an issue that is covered by the warranty, then they will charge the manufacturer, not you.

This could still take weeks, but if such a repair shop is in your vicinity, it might be faster than shipping everything over to Nikon.

Comment: If it's a matter of lost income, you could also try to negotiate a loaner for the period it would be away.

Comment: Could the person who downvoted this answer add justification, please?

Answer (score -1):

this may seem dum but I don't know how you are using the gear..so for what it's worth: 1. Are you switching the lenses while camera is powered OFF?
If so, it is correct. This procedure should NOT be done while camera is ON.